# Issue with background on UIGroupedTableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, interface

I'm using the following code to generate the background

```
    cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"list-item.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:00.0] ]autorelease];
```

which yields the following results where textLabel appears to have some sort of background around the text. Does anyone have experience with this problem? I made sure I set the backgroundview for the textlabel to nil but it still didn't work.

http://cl.ly/image/3K1P1O473v05 (Can't post image directly because of rep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UILabel` doesn't have a `backgroundView` property. Make sure that `backgroundColor` is set to `[UIColor clearColor]`.

Comment: It's almost always the easiest solution. Thanks Mark! If anyone else comes across here with the same question, make sure you also set cell.detailText.backgroundColor to clearColor as well!